# How open file with gedit withot terminal block?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

When I open file with

```
gedit templates/index.html
```

I see this in terminal and can't use it more:
[image]

How can I open file in text editor without blocking terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will enter the `&` to instruct the shell to launch Gedit in the background:

```
gedit templates/index.html &
```

"After the fact", i.e., after you forgot to enter the `&`, you still can send it to the background.

- In the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop the process
- The prompt is now released. Now type `bg` to send the stopped process to the background. Otherwise, Gedit will remain "stopped" appear as frozen.